# PHP - password_verify() no funciona

Tags: php

Sé que hay cientos de preguntas de este tipo, pero me estoy volviendo loco y no consigo que funcione, el inser funciona perfectamente.

Tengo una app en Android con en la que tengo un registro y login de usuarios. Lo estoy haciendo con mysqli

Código del login:

```
<?php

 include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
 
 $username = $_GET["username"];
 
 $Sql_Query = "select id, username, password from usuarios where username = '$username'";
 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 
    if(password_verify($_GET["password"], $row['password'])){
        while($ro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response[] = $ro;
        }
    }
    else echo "failed to log in(invalid password)";


?>
```

Código del insert por si acaso:

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
 
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
 
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 
 $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

 $Sql_Query = "insert into usuarios (username, password, email) values ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $hashed_password) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email) . "')";
 
 if(empty($username)){
     $result["success"] = "0";
    $result["message"] = "ERROR";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
 }
 else{
     if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){
    $result["success"] = "1";
    $result["message"] = "Registration success";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
 
    }
    else{
    $result["success"] = "0";
    $result["message"] = "error in Registration";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
 
    }
 }
 

?>
```

El insert me va perfecto, en la base de datos el campo de la contraseña es char(60) y el login
después que me imprima los datos en json para poder guardarlos en android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay algunos errores de seguridad en tu codigo, ya que no estas protegiendo los valores que vienen de los formularios que pueden provocar un **SQL INJECTION**

Como mencionas que el codigo `insert.php` te va bien ese no lo vamos a tocar, aunque no estaria nada mal que lo mejoraras.

Port parte del `login.php` veo que estas utilizando un ciclo inncesario, o si me podrias explicar para que lo estas usando seria de bastante ayuda, aqui te comparto como se puede mejorar y probablemente solucionar.

Tambien le añadiremos mas validaciones al login para poder tener mejor idea de lo que puede estar fallando al momento de que se trate de iniciar la sesion.

```
    <?php
    
     include 'DatabaseConfig.php' ;
     
     $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
     
     $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["username"]);
     $password= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["pass"]);
     
     $Sql_Query = "select id, username, password from usuarios where username = '$username'";
     
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
           if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])==1){
              echo "Logeado exitosamente";
              //procedes a asignar cookies o sesiones dependiendo de tu proyecto
           }else{
              echo "Error de inicio de sesion, contraseña invalida";
           }
        }else{
           echo "No hay usuarios registrado con ese nombre";
        }
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Soy bastante novato en PHP pero, en un principio el bucle lo estaba usando para imprimir los valores del select en un json para después recogerlos en Android, pero aún me sigue sin ir, se va por la rama de `"No hay usuarios registrado con ese nombre"`. Y es raro porque en cuanto quito la variable contraseña del archivo y de la url ya se va por el camino de `Contraseña inválida`

Comment: @Beardman Modifique el codigo utilizando el metodo `POST` para que trabajes con los valores dentro del script, ya que el metodo `GET` funciona diferente, intenta ahora. De igual forma tienes que tener tu formulario con `method="POST"`

Comment: en tanto al bucle, no es necesario utilizarlo ya que solamente estas obteniendo un valor de la consulta, no estas obteniendo una lista de resultado indexados.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar y a qué te refieres con tener el formulario con `method= "POST"` ?

Comment: el formulario donde envias los datos que quieres ingresar, lo puedes poner porfa?

Comment: Lo mando todo por url

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de la URI con la que manejas los datos?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128989/discussion-between-ruben-and-beardman).

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema y todavía no funcionaba a pesar de asegurarme de que las columnas de mi base de datos fueran varchar(255), que los hashes fueran de 60 caracteres y de que mi codificación fuera UTF-8 hasta el final. Soy bastante nuevo en PHP y SQL, así que no pretenderé entender exactamente por qué funcionó, pero logré solucionarlo, así que espero que esta publicación ayude a otras personas con el mismo problema.

Resultó que la razón subyacente por la que password_verify() no verificaba mis hashes era porque había hecho una declaración preparada que usaba un procedimiento almacenado anteriormente en el script sin obtener todos los resultados de la consulta correctamente para borrar el búfer, antes de cerrar y reabrir la conexión para realizar la siguiente consulta. Llamar a next_result() en mysqli_link después de cerrar la declaración asegurará que se consuman los resultados.
Además, estaba usando otra declaración preparada con un procedimiento almacenado para hacer la inserción de la contraseña, pero todavía necesitaba hacer llamadas a store_result() y free_result() aunque no se devolvieron conjuntos de resultados de la inserción. Supongo que la combinación de estas cosas estaba corrompiendo mis datos en algún lugar a lo largo de la línea, lo que resultó en que password_verify() devolviera falso en hashes aparentemente idénticos.

Comment: Podrías indicar al menos que esta respuesta es de otra persona, saludos.